# Google Play: are free in-app items allowed?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

It's really hard to research my question, because the word "free" causes tons of hits about free apps and how to scam the store to get in-app purchases for free.

According to https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153485?hl=en

> Note: In-app items can't have a set price of "0" (free).

Ok, so you can't "sell" free items directly in the official Play Store. However, I still want to list free items alongside the paid ones. It's not too hard to circumvent Google and implement free items myself (the paid ones are official products, and free ones come from my back end), but my question is: does Google allow this? Is it a policy violation?

Are there apps out there that do this?

Comment: What is the point? Just give it to them ha.

Comment: if you add in-app products price those will be paid others will be free we don't have  to set price as 0.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is behind this "free items" model.

Main point of Google's policy is to get 30% of any possible income you do using Google Play. If you sell for 0$ you can share 30% of 0$ with Google, similar to how you do it, when you publish a free app.

Other thing is if you sell something for 0$ at Google Play attracting people to another place (outside of Google Play), where you then sell something for real money. In this case you receive some indirect profit from using Google Play (you attract people Google Play "shares" with you), but you don't share a part of your profit with Google. I don't think Google will like it.

Comment: The reason for having free items is to encourage users to use the in-app store. The hope is that free items get them into the store, and once they're there they might be enticed to buy stuff that isn't free.

Comment: That's fine and even good for Google, because this help to increase sells via Google Play.